# How does Angular compile the DOM and process the directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am really curious about Angular's working mechanism (its workflow/pipeline). Short of diving into the source code, I don't find any material explaining this clearly.

Can anyone explain how Angular compile the HTML and directives?

Comment: Is this useful https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap ? What would you like to know more specifically?

Comment: Go through https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile .

Comment: These docs are all good starting points for understanding Angular, but mostly they are conceptual. A lot of details are not covered, like, what is the result of compilation? A js function, or js+some data structure?

Comment: Sometimes you have to dig into a the source code for this stuff. Most of the docs are just for how to use and some information around that.